How to save a keras model just for inference?
I trained a CNN model and saved it as a .keras file. Now I want other people to use it for making predictions. I am planning on deploying it using a flask server and package the whole thing in an exe. The problem is when I do a .summary() after I load it back, I am able to see the entire model architecture. I was also able to see the values of the hyperparameters that I used when I trained the model.
What is the best way to serve the model just for inference ? (I want the model specifics to be hidden) and how should the data be passed into whatever I am saving the model/weights as for predictions?
I use keras 2.10.0 and tf 2.10.1.
The most straightforward approach in the keras docs was to use .export() but it seems that it is available only from keras 3.

At some point, the running application needs to know the architecture of the model. The weights alone are insufficient to do anything.
You could try encrypting the bits that control the model architecture in your executable and just sharing the weights (which you can extract using get_weights), but this is a lot of hoops to jump through, very uncommon, and  unlikely to stop a determined snooper from figuring out the model architecture.
Model architectures aren't the secret sauce in proprietary models. What makes one model commercially different compared to another is the training process, both in terms of hardware and training data access.
In fact many commercial model architectures are open source. (See GPT-4's technical review for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.08774)

Thanks! I browsed a lot to find a good way but I haven't found anything straightforward yet..... So my approach now is to save just the architecture and the weights, excluding other model parameters. But there seems to be a lack of resource online on how to achieve this. There is plenty of docs about how to save the entire model (everything...) but not how to save specific things and reload them back. Do you have any suggestions on how I can approach this?

I suggest asking a new question outlining the specific data you are trying to save and reload, and upvoting and accepting this answer if it was helpful ; )

Will do! I do not have enough reputation to upvote as I am new to this platform I'm afraid. It did help a bit. Thank you!
